# insert sort alphabetically using doubly linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

Is this correct? I used the code I did when sorting numbers I don't know if it works the same with strings. When I run it, there are no errors detected, but when I try to view it, the inputs does not appear.

```
void add(node **h, node **t){
node *temp, *ptr;
char s[20];

    temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    printf ("-INSERT-");
    printf("Fruit: ");
     scanf("%s", temp->fruit);
    printf("Color: ");
        scanf("%s", temp->color);
    printf("Texture: ");
     scanf("%s", temp->texture);




if ( (*h)->next==(*t) ) {
    temp->next = (*h)->next;
        temp->prev = (*h);
        (*h)->next->prev = temp;
        (*h)->next = temp;
        }


else{

          if(strcmp(s, temp->fruit)){
          temp->next = (*h)->next;
          temp->prev = (*h);
          (*h)->next->prev = temp; 
          (*h)->next = temp;  
          }


else if(strcmp(s, temp->fruit)){
             temp->next = (*t);
             temp->prev = (*t)->prev;
             (*t)->prev->next = temp;
             (*t)->prev = temp;
             }

        else{

             while(strcmp(s, ptr->fruit)){
             ptr = ptr->next;          
             }


             temp->next = ptr->next;
             temp->prev = ptr;
             ptr->next->prev = temp;
             ptr->next = temp;

             }

    }
```

Comment: I've added the C tag, change it if it's not right.

Comment: Check the value returned by `strcmp` in any good reference. You are testing if your string is equal, but then you ignore whether it is "larger" or "smaller" than the expected string and so you are inserting in the wrong place in about 50% of the cases.